# jquery remove by parent div

Tags: jquery

Please consider following snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Person Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes belong to grid-based css framework named 'bootstrap' and are used for positioning and styling.

The 'row' is inside of the single form. The form provides input for many persons. Each 'row' corresponds to a single person with its input details. (in this example I have only one property for simplicity - 'Person Name') So I can have many snippets/'rows' like this in a single form.

What I would like to do is to create a button which would be inside every 'row' and whenever it is clicked it would delete the entire row in which it resides, but would not affect  other rows which belong to other persons' input details.

So far as I understood the easiest option would be usage of jQuery'.remove' method. However it would require id enumeration of every 'row' in this case, which I can generate on server-side, but not in this case, lets just assume that it is not allowed - I don't have 'id' attributes and I can't add them, so I can't point function at the row id to delete. If I fetch class to '.remove' method the button will obviously delete all the rows.

Just to illustrate the situation. Multiple rows, notice the buttons.

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Person Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-medium">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button type="button" onclick="deleteTheEntireRow()" class="btn btn primary">Delete Person</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Person Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-medium">
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <button type="button" onclick="deleteTheEntireRow()" class="btn btn primary">Delete Person</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

I apologise for formatting.

Essentially what a button must do:
 detect and select just its fourth parent 'row', so I could apply `.remove' method.

Comment: I've cleaned up your formatting. Notice that the two divs with class `row` have no end tag.

Comment: _never really understood the overcomplicated code formatting in here_ It's actually pretty easy. Just indent your code in your text editor with spaces not tabs, then copy/paste in SO and select the code and press the toolbar button `{}`.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I tried to work with .remove method to my current knowledge extent and as I come from Java perspective I find it difficult to work with JS and jQuery , that is the reason I ask the question. The script would require sufficient knowledge as it would work with relative elements. And the basic example would be good for me to learn. Seriously ... :-\

Comment: @elclanrs copying from eclipse doesn't do?

Comment: As long as you convert tab to spaces it should be fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).closest("div.row").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

*I've remove the `onclick` property in the HTML by the way*

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksBjU/)

Comment: I believe that is exactly what is required. I will play with it and see if it works in my context, then accept. Thanks! (upvoted)

Answer (score 3):

Add some class to every button like `deleteRow` and then use:

```
$(".deleteRow").on("click",function() { 
   $(this).closest(".row").remove()
});
```

Comment: your code works fine on my project but why does it need double click at first to delete the row ? any idea to do it at one click for the first time ?! By the way I am doing it on <a></a>

Comment: The question is 2 years old and I don't remember the problem very well. It would help if you posted jsFiddle with your code so I can take a look

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>information</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="removeRow(this)">Text</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="removeRow(this)">Text</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
removeRow = function(el) {
    $(el).parents("tr").remove()       
}
```